# Recursive values and move forward values

Tags: sql-server

I have two tables  and table A is having which is matching with B and all the 10 version is matching some codes, some code is changed from version to version. but one of the domain code alue is not available in version 10 and 11 . But automatically the value of 9 should be carried forward to 10 and 11. I am using while condition and CTE recursive it is not giving the result expected

Comment: Please provide sample data and desired results.

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.